# Get Status of all Azure RM VMs using Rest

Tags: rest, azure

I'm trying to get the status of all the VMs in a resource group using rest interface for Azure RM.

I can get the status of 1 VM by using the URL
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[SubscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[ResourceGroup]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines/[serverName]?$expand=instanceView

and I can get all the VMs using this URL
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[SubscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[ResourceGroup]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines

however this doesn't return the status of the VMs.  I tried passing $expand=instanceView but that doesn't have any affect when I'm getting all the VMs.

Comment: I doubt you can do that since the `instanceView` thing is tied to the VM resource, not the resource group or Microsoft.Compute provider. You'll have to iterate though the VMs and call `$expand=instanceView`.

Comment: I know it has been 3 years since this question was made. But my answer is the correct way to do it today, when this is an actual and recurring need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the status from VMs, in just one API request/call you can use:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2020-06-01&statusOnly=true
```

From this Azure RESTful API - Virtual Machines - List All [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall):

> statusOnly=true enables fetching run time status of all Virtual
> Machines in the subscription.

So setting `statusOnly=true` allows you to receive back the `provisioningState` property and an `instanceView` object, which contains the `PowerState` like "PowerState/running", "PowerState/stopped", etc...

Also, there is a lot of other useful and important information inside the returned `instanceView` object. More about it on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/instanceview).

*After hours searching, that's the only way I found to get back all instances' status in just one call. All other approaches that I saw were using a loop, and executing one API request for every VM, which is awful slow, and depending on the application and number of VMs, unacceptable...*

Comment: I know the documentation says to use the statusOnly=true parameter to get the status of all the VMs, however that flag has no affect.

Comment: @Rossini Did you try it with which Endpoint? Because I believe the 2nd Endpoint on your question is deprecated. I could not found any documentation related to it. Also I believe it won't work with this flag/parameter. I just made a request with postman, using the specific endpoint I specified here (which differs on path and version of yours), setting that parameter to true, and I got back all the information, including the `instanceView` object, with all the `PorwerStates` of my VMs.

Comment: I missed that you are using a different end point.  I'm using the Virtual Machines - List end point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/list  where as you are using the List all end point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall  the List All end point is exactly what I am looking for, thanks for the help

Comment: Infuriatingly, this work. You'd think they would allow getting this info as additional information on top of vm data but no, you need to make a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

> this doesn't return the status of the VMs. I tried passing $expand=instanceView but that doesn't have any affect when I'm getting all the VMs.

From [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines#VirtualMachines_Get), we could find that `GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2016-03-30[&$expand]` enable us to use the $expand option to expand property, but `GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2016-03-30` does not support the $expand option. Perhaps the API method that lists all of the virtual machine in the specified resource group does not return an IQueryable or does not allow query options.

As evilSnobu said, you could try to do it in two steps: list all VMs in the specified resource group and iterate though all VMs and extract name property, and then send request to retrieve information of specified VM and use $expand in the query string of the request to expand instanceView property.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}?api-version=2016-03-30&$expand=instanceView", subscriptionid, resourcegroup, vmname));

request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
```

[image]

Comment: how do i pass the client id and secret/ or how to get token?